# initializer_list with one element

Tags: c++, initializer-list

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Obj{
    int a = 6;
};

void func(const std::vector<Obj>& a) {
    std::cout << "here" << std::endl;
}

void func(const Obj& a) {
    std::cout << "there" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Obj obj, obj2;
    func({obj});
    func({obj, obj2});
}
```

Expected output:

```
here
here
```

Actual output:

```
there
here
```

It seems `{obj}` doesn't initialize a vector, but rather an object. I guess there is some priority order when it comes to which type it initializes. How do I control it precisely?

(Examples compiled with g++ (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1) 8.3.0.)

Comment: That link doesn’t answer my question though: how do I control it more precisely? ie, how to use initializer list to unit a single item vector?

Comment: See follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55700589/use-initializer-list-to-create-single-item-vector/55709932