# Use initializer list to create single item vector

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I have a function `func` which is overloaded to take either a `std::vector<Obj>` argument or a `Obj` argument.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Obj {
    int a = 6;
};

void func(const std::vector<Obj>& a) {
    std::cout << "here" << std::endl;
}

void func(const Obj& a) {
    std::cout << "there" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Obj obj, obj2;
    func({obj});
    func({obj, obj2});
}
```

Actual output:

```
there
here
```

Expected output:

```
here
here
```

It seems `{obj}` doesn't initialize a vector, but rather an object. I guess there is some priority order when it comes to which type it initializes. How do I control it precisely?

(Examples compiled with g++ (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1) 8.3.0.)

I found a possible duplicate ([c++11 single element vector initialization in a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46565165/c11-single-element-vector-initialization-in-a-function-call)), although my question remains unanswered:

I understand that `{obj}` can resolve to an object rather a vector of a single element and the former takes priority. But is there a way to use `{}` to create a single item vector (so that `foo` resolves to the `std::vector` overload)? I could create a vector explicitly but `{}` seems nicer.

Comment: You should add all revelant details from that question to this one.

Comment: It seems to be that your question is indirectly answered in the link: you can't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the linked question duplicate (the original) there is no way to force the resolution in favour of the overload taking `std::initializer_list`.

The original signatures (using `int` to simplify):

```
void func(const std::vector<int> &a); 
void func(const int &a);
```

Since I have encountered this many times I typically do this:

```
func(std::vector<int>{10});
```

I am not aware of any shorter way of doing this because using actual type `std::initializer_list` that would do the same is even more verbose. But on the birght side it at least makes what you are doing perfectly clear since `{10}` is really ambiguous if not accompanied with the type.

Comment: You could even do `std::vector{10}`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Right you are but only since C++17 with template argument deduction.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

Excerpt (from [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#list-3.9), emphasis mine):

> "[...] if the initializer list has a **single** element of type E and
>   either T is not a reference type or its referenced type is
>   reference-related to E, the object or reference is initialized from
>   that element (by copy-initialization for copy-list-initialization, or by **direct-initialization** for direct-list-initialization)"

Therefore, in your linked example, `{obj}` will "decay" to `obj` and the overload will resolve to `void func(const Obj& a)`.

As stated in the other answer, you can explicitely call `func(std::vector {obj})` to call the vector overload instead.